# Using Rails nested_form without any associated models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, associations, nested-forms

Using Ryan's [nested_form](https://github.com/ryanb/nested_form) gem to create a form. I want the functionality of the `link_to_add` and `link_to_remove` methods, but nothing about this form has anything to do with any of my models; I'm not saving it at all.

```
= simple_nested_form_for :non_model_object do |f|
  = f.input :input1
  = f.simple_fields_for :non_model_child do |child|
    = child.input :child_input_1
    = child.link_to_remove 'Remove'
  = f.link_to_add 'Add', :non_model_child
```

`non_model_object` is obviously not something I have in the database. `non_model_object` "has many" `non_model_children` for the sake of this form, but again, this doesn't exist in the database either. The error I'm receiving is:

`Invalid association. Make sure that accepts_nested_attributes_for is used for :non_model_child association.`

This obviously makes sense, but I can't add that in to the `non_model_object` class because it doesn't exist.

The purpose of this form is simply for users to fill it out, and it is going to send me a csv of their input. Thoughts on how to best accomplish this?

Thanks!

Rails 4.2.5.1
ruby 2.1.2
nested_form 0.3.2

Answer (score 0):

You can use the same orientation as the Ryan Bates used in their screencasts. He exemplified the nested forms these links:

- [raillscast nested forms part-1](http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1)
- [railscasts nested forms part-2](http://railscasts.com/episodes/197-nested-model-form-part-2)

I think that will help in your problem.

Answer (score -1):

You can use [cocoon gem](https://rubygems.org/gems/cocoon), this gem is easy and simple for nested forms.

I use this gem in all my projects. :)

Comment: I'd prefer to stick with nested_form if at all possible, as the entire app has already been built using it

Comment: ok, just informed another possibility which greatly facilitates the development and works with various tools like simple form, formtastic, rails pure and more. Out that allows use with erb, haml and thin. I believe that also serve for other users who go through this problem. :)